# How do I fix a warped kitchen cabinet?

Tags: wood, kitchens, woodworking, cabinets

The side wall of the cabinet is slightly warped after I used the high temperature self-clean feature on the oven. This cabinet has three large drawers in it and now they won't close.  The wall of the cabinet is warping in slightly (a few millimeters) and is squeezing the drawers enough that they scrape against the side of the cabinet.

How should I repair this cabinet?

Comment: At least they weren't stuck closed! The drawer guides need to be realigned. What style and how they are mounted would dictate the specifics. The other question is how to prevent this from happening again.

Comment: Luckily, I had taken the drawers out before I cleaned the oven so that the drawer fronts wouldn't get damaged.  I couldn't find any adjustments that I could make to the rails.  Everything was screwed in as tightly as possible.

Comment: When I clean my oven I pull it out. I do it because I don't like how hot my microwave gets but might be a good idea for you next time.

Comment: @longneck - that is really good advice.

Comment: I pulled my ranged out into the kitchen to clean it too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I decided to try to install a cross brace inside the cabinet to spread the walls enough so the drawers would fit.

I made a trip to the hardware store and picked up:

- A 1x6 pine board
- Angle brackets with screws

Then I:

1. measured the front opening of the cabinet.
2. cut a piece off the pine board 2mm longer than the cabinet is wide.
3. used a rubber mallet to tap the board into place as a cross brace just underneath the top drawer.
4. tested the drawers to make sure they opened and closed with the cross brace in place
5. permanently attached the cross brace with the angle brackets.

It works perfectly.  I was prepared to add a second cross brace underneath the middle drawer, but all the drawers are working well without it.

Here is a picture of the repair with a red circle around the board that I added.

[image: Added cross brace to cabinet]

Comment: Why I never use the self clean.  Last time I turned it on my cabinet fronts got scorched.  Looks like you are the right path to fixing everything.